# click dynamic php project title links to get full project details on profile page in php

Tags: php

please help. I am building a website where people can upload their projects. I designed it in such a way that one person can have multiple projects. I am fairly new to php and I know I posted way too much code but I need help

I have been able to make the project titles for each user show dynamically when they login in. The problem I have is how do I make each link load up the page with the full project details. Right now it only shows the first project details no matter what title is clicked. Below is the profile page.

```
<?php if(isset($login_projectTittle)){
echo "Click to see your projects";
?>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM fullprojectdetails WHERE user_id=$login_id";
if ($result=mysqli_query($connection,$query)){
if($count = mysqli_num_rows($result)){

/*  because of the mysqli_fetch_object function the variables have to be    $rowe->title (as an object) */
while($rowe = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

?>
<?php $_SESSION['projectstuff'] = $rowe ->projecttitle; ?>
<?php $_SESSION['projectIdNew'] = $rowe ->projectid; ?>
<a href="project.php"><?php  echo $rowe ->projecttitle; ?></a>

<br>

<?php
}
/* mysqli_free_result frees p the result in the variable ths allowing for a new one each time */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
}
}
else {echo "";}



                            ?>
```

I used POST to send the data to the database.

The page that should load up the full project details is the project page. Contents to be displayed on this page are drawn from the session code which is included in the project page and displayed below

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
require('databaseConnect.php');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Selecting Database
require('databaseSelect.php');
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User (MYSQL Inner Join used here) took hours to learn
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($connection, "select user.user_emailaddress, user.user_fullname, user.user_id, fullprojectdetails.fileToUpload, fullprojectdetails.projecttitle,
fullprojectdetails.projectcreated, fullprojectdetails.projectcategory, fullprojectdetails.projectcountry, fullprojectdetails.projectdetails,
fullprojectdetails.fundTime, fullprojectdetails.fundinggoal, fullprojectdetails.fileToUpload2, fullprojectdetails.name, fullprojectdetails.biography,
fullprojectdetails.yourlocation, fullprojectdetails.website, fullprojectdetails.fileToUpload3, fullprojectdetails.projectdetails2, fullprojectdetails.accountName, fullprojectdetails.bankName, fullprojectdetails.accountType,
 fullprojectdetails.accountNo,fullprojectdetails.user_id, fullprojectdetails.projectid from user inner join fullprojectdetails on user.user_id=fullprojectdetails.user_id  where user.user_emailaddress='$user_check'");
 //saving variables to be used in every page with session_new included
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['user_emailaddress'];
$login_fullname =$row['user_fullname'];
$login_id =$row['user_id'];
$login_projectTittle = $row['projecttitle'];
$login_projectLocation = $row['yourlocation'];
$login_projectCategory = $row['projectcategory'];
$login_projectFundGoal = $row['fundinggoal'];
$login_projectSummary = $row['projectdetails'];
$login_projectWebsite = $row['website'];
$login_projectVideo = $row['fileToUpload3'];
$login_Pic = $row['fileToUpload2'];
$login_projectID = $row['projectid'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectPic = $row['fileToUpload'];
$login_projectFullDet = $row['projectdetails2'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: login.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Below is the project page code

```
<?php
include('session_new.php');
/*echo $_SESSION['projectstuff'];
if (isset($_POST['profile_btn'])){*/
/*  if (isset ($_SESSION['projectstuff'])){
        $ses_sql=mysqli_query($connection, "select *  from fullproject where projecttitle='{$_SESSION['projectstuff']}");*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<!--require for the nav var-->
<?php require 'logged-in-nav-bar.php';?>

<div id= "upperbodyproject">
    <div id= "projectheader">
    <h2>  <?php echo $login_projectTittle; ?><h2>
    </div>
        <!-- video and funder div-->
            <div id = "vidFundCont">
            <div id = "video">
            <video width='100%' height='100%' controls> <source src="<?php echo $login_projectVideo ?>" type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</source></video>
            </div>
            <div id = "funders">
            <p> <strong> 20 </strong> <br> <br><span>funders </span>  </p> <br> <br> <br>
            <p> </p><br>
            <p> <span>funded of N<?php echo $login_projectFundGoal ; ?> </span><p><br> <br> <br>
            <p><strong> 15 </strong> <br> <span> <br> days left </span></p><br> <br> <br>
            <button id = "projectPageButton"><a href = "fund.php"> Fund This Project </a></button>
            </div>
            <div id = "clearer"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- location and project condition -->
                <div id = "location">
                <p> Location: <?php echo $login_projectLocation ; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Category:<?php echo $login_projectCategory ; ?> </p>
                </div>
                <div id ="projectconditions">
                <p> This project will only be funded if N<?php echo $login_projectFundGoal ; ?> is funded before the project deadline</p>
                </div>
                <div id = "clearer"> </div>
                <!--project summary and profile -->
                    <div id = "nutshell">
                    <p><?php echo $login_projectSummary ; ?> </p> <br> <br>
                    <span>Share:</span> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<a href =# ><img src="images/1484370173_facebook.png" alt="facebook logo" height="42" width="42"> </a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                    <a href =# ><img src="images/1484370205_twitter.png" alt="twitter logo" height="42" width="42"></a>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                    <a href =# ><img src="images/1484370192_instagram.png" alt="instagram logo" height="42" width="42"></a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                    </div>
                    <div id = "projProfile">
                        <div id = "projProfileTop">
                        <img src="<?php echo $login_Pic ; ?>" width = "50%" height = "100%">
                        </div>
                            <div id ="projProfileBottom">
                            <br>
                            <p id = "profileNameStyle"> Name: <?php echo $login_fullname; ?>  </p> <br>
                            <p> Website: <?php echo $login_projectWebsite ; ?>   </p> <br>
                            <p> Email: <?php echo $login_session; ?>  </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "clearer"> </div>
                    <!-- about and reward title -->
                        <div id = "aboutProjH">
                        <h2> About This Project </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div id = "rewardH">
                        <h2> Rewards For Supporting This Project</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div id = "clearer"> </div>
                        <!--project pic and dynamic rewards-->
                            <div id = "projPic">
                            <img src="<?php echo $login_projectPic;?>" width = "100%" height = "100%">
                            </div>


                                        <div id = "rewardDet">
                                            <br>
                                            <span><?php echo $login_projectFullDet; ?> </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id = "clearer"> </div>




                            <div id = "clearer"> </div>
                            <!-- project details and empty divs -->
                            <?php

                            // code to select content form database and display dynamically in a div
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM reward WHERE user_id=$login_id";
                            if ($result=mysqli_query($connection,$query)){
                                if($count = mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                                    /*  because of the mysqli_fetch_object function the variables have to be $rowe->title (as an object) */
                                    while($rowe = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
                                        ?>
                                <div id = "projDet">


                                <p> <h2><?php echo "N".$rowe->pledgeAmount. " " . "or more"; ?></h2></p> <br>
                                <p><span> <br><?php echo $rowe ->title; ?></span></p> <br>

                                <p> <span><?php echo $rowe ->description; ?></span></p> <br>
                                <p> <span>Estimated Delivery Time: <br> <?php echo $rowe ->deliverytime . " ". $rowe ->deliveryyear; ?></span></p> <br>
                                <p> <span><?php echo $rowe ->shippingdetails; ?></p></span> <br>
                                <p> <span>Number of Rewards Available: <br><?php echo $rowe ->reward1No; ?></span></p>


                                </div>
                                <!--<div id = "bsideProjDet">
                                </div> -->
                                <div id = "clearer"> </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            /* mysqli_free_result frees p the result in the variable ths allowing for a new one each time */
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        }
                    }

                    /* display dynamic form */
                    /*$s_sql=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM reward WHERE user_id=$login_id");
$rowe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s_sql);
?>
            <?php echo $rowe['title']; ?><br><br>
            <?php echo $rowe['pledgeAmount']; ?><br><br>
    <?php echo $rowe['description']; ?><br><br>
<?php echo $rowe['deliverytime']; ?><br><br>
<?php echo $rowe['deliveryyear']; ?><br><br>
<?php echo $rowe['shippingdetails']; ?><br><br>
<?php echo $rowe['reward1No']; ?><br><br> */
?>
                                    <div id = "reportProj">
                                    <button id = "projectPageButton"> Report This Project To Gbedion</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<div id = "bsideReportProj"> </div>-->
                                    <div id = "clearer"> </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
</div>
<?php
/*}
}
else {
    echo "Select a project";
}*/
?>

<!-- page footer-->
<?php require 'logged-in-footer.php';?>
</body>

</html>
```

The project Id is the primary key and user id is the foreign key in fullprojectdetails table. If more database details are needed please let me know. Had to abandon this project for a month because of this problem.

Comment: as much as I would like to help your code is a mess please only post the relevant parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't store the projectid and project title on a session variable, on the profile page, just create a normal variable and store them on that variable, then when you linking to project.php create a query strings, with the id of the project then with the title of the project, ie `<a href="project.php?id=DynamicId&title=DynamicTitle">Dynamic Project Title</a>`  I believe when you store the id's of the projects in a session, once you click on one project, the browser will always use that id no matter which project you click next, until you unset/destroy the sessions(logout).

there fore this on profile :

```
<?php $_SESSION['projectstuff'] = $rowe ->projecttitle;?>
<?php $_SESSION['projectIdNew'] = $rowe ->projectid; ?>
<a href="project.php"><?php  echo $rowe ->projecttitle; ?></a>
```

should change to :

```
<?php $projectstuff = $rowe ->projecttitle; ?>
<?php $projectIdNew = $rowe ->projectid; ?>
<a href="project_details.php?projectid=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($projectIdNew));?>&projecttitle=<?php echo $projectstuff;?>"><?php  echo $rowe ->projecttitle; ?></a>
```

Then on projetc.php

you first check if the id isset and also the title, then do your queries

this is how you would do it

**project.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//validate your sessions
if (isset($_GET['projectid']) && isset($_GET['projecttitle'])) {

    $currentProjectID = urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['projectid']));
    $projectTitle     = $_GET['projecttitle'];
?>
        <?php
    require 'logged-in-nav-bar.php';
?>

    <div id= "upperbodyproject">
        <div id= "projectheader">
            <h2>  <?php echo $projectTitle; //from the query string ?></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- get the details of this project -->

        <?php    
            $query = "SELECT * FROM fullprojectdetails WHERE projectid=$currentProjectID";

    // Continue your staff then

?>

</div><!-- upperbodyproject -->
    <?php
} else {

    echo "could not find project id";
}

?>
```

Hope this will help point you to the correct direction, I would suggest that you look at mysqli prepared statements, and also at PDO prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you this was very useful. It worked. But i had to remove ! from isset($_GET['projecttitle']) to get it to work as required. Thanks again especially with the messy code I sent.

Comment: oh yes you are write a made a mess there.. @Afe thanks for sporting that... Please upvote and mark the answer if if was useful